# Shuffling a Set of Rows in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, shuffle

I am new with VBA so I am having some problems sorting this out.

I have a set of rows which I have to record a macro to shuffle ALL rows. That is, there must be no rows left unchanged after I run the macro.

And the thing is, this set of values is not a single column. There are several columns which must be taken into account. Shuffling has to be made without changing the entire row, and the shuffle has to occur for all of the columns.

A very simple example:
Values before shuffle:

> A  1
>
> B  2
>
> C  3

After shuffle:

> C  3
>
> A  1
>
> B  2

in addition, this code has to generate random orders every time it runs, hence it has to be flexible.

Edit: I have tried using VLookup, but it became very complex and didn't run properly.

```
Sub Shuffle()

Dim i as Variant
Dim j as Variant
Dim myTable as Range
Set myTable = Sheets(1).Range("A1:C10")

'after setting everything up I tried getting the entire row and assigning it to variables, in the worksheet I have 3 columns.
For i=1 to myTable.Rows.Count
Col1=Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(...
```

Here I am trying to capture the value for other columns as I select the first value. But the problem is that the first value must be selected randomly. And it doesn't necessarily mean that the value I will select for the first column shouldn't be the same for the row I'll select. My data is close to the following:

> 1  A  M
>
> 1  B  M
>
> 1  C  K
>
> 2  A  M.. and so on.

So for the first row, I also must be able to select the following two rows, which I could not satisfy via the Vlookup function. Maybe an index value for rows may be used for randomization, but I have no idea how to do that.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: interesting question..........do you have an unused column on the worksheet??

Comment: how does such a poor question get an upvote!?

Comment: I have tried using the VLookup function, though it got very complex and confusing (and it would be even worse with a greater amount of data), I am sure there must be an easier way, however I am clueless.

Yes, I do have unused columns on the worksheet.

If you could tell me why you think my question is poor, I'll try improving it by adding more information.

Thank you all for the feedback.

Comment: The middle row is not shuffled!

Comment: Also add that vlookup thing and your algorithm to the question

Comment: Sorry about that! I will change it immediately.

The sad thing is not even the vlookup function was complete. But I will add it anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that if you shuffle them "randomly" then every row must have moved? That's not random. Random would be unpredictable, but in your scenario, you could predict that a certain row wouldn't be in the same place. Truly random would allow a row to be in the same position after the shuffle.

Comment: why do you want to do this? what is your end goal here?

Comment: Well it's not completely random. That's why it's impossible to use random functions of excel in this case.Maybe it can be clearer if I put it this way: A row has to change into other rows in the sheet randomly. It shouldn't stay the same after we run the code.

The goal is to achieve different sorting of all rows every time we run the code. (But every row has to be changed, there shouldn't be any rows left behind that are unchanged.)

Maybe if there are some functions to randomize rows from a certain range in excel, it would help. (In this case we have to define different ranges for all cases)

Comment: *So for the first row, I also must be able to select the following two rows* <-- shot in the dark here, but do you mean: "For the first *column* I also must be able to select the following two *columns*? (i.e., the entire selected row's range ("A1:C1", "A3:C3", etc...)).

Comment: No, I'll aid the question with a picture to make it clearer in just a minute.

Comment: I could not add a picture because appearantly I need some reputation to do so. I will do my best to explain what I meant in that sentence:

An alternative I thought of had to do with checking for the values in each cell in column A, then randomizing accordingly. But such an approach does not work because some rows begin with the same value. If we code in such a way that the next random row CAN'T begin with the same value as the row we're randomizing for, it won't work.

Hope I could clear your doubt, please don't hesitate to tell me if I wasnt clear enough.

Comment: How many rows are we talking about?

Comment: The utility and elegance of `VLookup()` always fills me with a sense of awe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have data in A2:B27 with headers in A1:B1. In C1, put "OriginalRow" and in D1 enter "Rand".

This code sorts the rows on the Rand column until each row is in a different spot. With 26 rows, it rarely took over 5 loops. Even with only three rows, it rarely took more than 7 tries.

```
Public Sub Shuffle()

    Dim lCnt As Long
    Dim rRng As Range

    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A2:D27")

    'Record which row it starts on
    With rRng.Columns(3)
        .Formula = "=ROW()"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    Do
        'Add a random value for sorting
        With rRng.Columns(4)
            .Formula = "=RAND()"
            .Value = .Value
        End With

        'Sort on random value
        Sheet1.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        Sheet1.Sort.SortFields.Add rRng.Columns(4), xlSortOnValues, xlAscending
        With Sheet1.Sort
            .SetRange rRng.Offset(-1).Resize(rRng.Rows.Count + 1)
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .Apply
        End With

        lCnt = lCnt + 1
    'if any rows are the same as the starting row
    'do it again
    Loop Until ShuffleComplete(rRng.Columns(3)) Or lCnt > 100

    Debug.Print lCnt

End Sub

Public Function ShuffleComplete(rRng As Range) As Boolean

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim bReturn As Boolean

    bReturn = True

    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
        If rCell.Value = rCell.Row Then
            bReturn = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next rCell

    ShuffleComplete = bReturn

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The algorithm looks awesome! I am new in VBA, so there are some points I don't understand clearly. I didn't understand how we completed sorting rows out. How does the "=RAND()" function end up randomizing rows?

One last question, when I run the code I get an error saying: "Loop Without Do" why might that be occuring?

Thank you very very much!

Comment: The code manipulates the Sort object to sort the rows. But if you understand how to do it in the UI, that maybe more instructive. Next to your data, put =RAND() and fill down. That puts a random number next to each row. Now sort the data on that column. Your rows will be in a random order. That's all the code is doing at its core. If you copy the code exactly, it will compile. Loop without Do means you don't have the Do statement or, more likely, you have an If or With block that isn't properly closed.

Comment: Works perfectly fine. I worked on the specific example I have and one I adapted this algorithm into it everything went perfect!

Thanks!